# Zend Framework 2 Redirect in onBootStrap with site URL

Tags: php, redirect, zend-framework2

I'm trying to redirect in Module.php in Zend Framework 2.

I got the code online and it is working but not as expected.

I'm trying to redirect to a different module.

Here is the code.

```
public function onBootStrap($e){
    $container = new Container();
    if(!$container || !$container->admin_id){
        //  Assuming your login route has a name 'login', this will do the assembly
        // (you can also use directly $url=/path/to/login)
        $url = $e->getRouter()->assemble(array('action' => 'login'), array('name' => 'admin'));
        $response=$e->getResponse();
        $response->getHeaders()->addHeaderLine('Location', $url);
        $response->setStatusCode(302);
        $response->sendHeaders();
        // When an MvcEvent Listener returns a Response object,
        // It automatically short-circuit the Application running
        // -> true only for Route Event propagation see Zend\Mvc\Application::run

        // To avoid additional processing
        // we can attach a listener for Event Route with a high priority
        $stopCallBack = function($event) use ($response){
            $event->stopPropagation();
            return $response;
        };
        //Attach the "break" as a listener with a high priority
        $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, $stopCallBack,-10000);
        return $response;
    }
 }
```

It works and redirects me to `http://localhost/admin/login`
But my actual site url is `http://localhost/MantissaAdmin/public/`
So it should be redirecting me to `http://localhost/MantissaAdmin/public/admin/login`

How can I redirect to `http://localhost/MantissaAdmin/public/admin/login` ?

Comment: Did you tried passing 'force_canonical' => true to the options argument. Also a RewriteBase might be necessary in your .htacces if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to grab [the ZF2 redirect plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#the-redirect-plugin) from the controller and use this for redirecting to another route. You can check an example [here in another question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13317859/1697459).